# How long does Windows store event logs from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, logging, windows-services, event-log

I'm using the Windows Event Log to record logs from a custom Windows Service.

If I need to read a log of say, yesterday, I go to the EventViewer, look for my EventLog and read it. But I'm afraid of what would happen if I needed to access a log from months or even years ago. Is it possible? How long does Windows store my logs? Is it configurable from my Service?

Should I use a third-party logger like NLog, which might be better than the Windows Event Log for my service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, each log (eg: Application, System, etc...) is configured to reach 20 Mb max, using the [FIFO principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)).

You can [modify this size and set up an archiving policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721981(v=ws.11).aspx) instead of the FIFO method, and you'll never loose your logs again.

Comment: What's an Mo?  Is that 20 months, or meant to be 20 Megabytes (MB)?

Comment: @SharpC and for any future readers, yes, the max size is 20 megabytes